# Retrieving only certain columns with Rails 3 where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Not sure why I can't find out how to do this easily... Obviously I could do it with raw SQL, but I'm trying to familiarize myself with ActiveRecord.

```
results = Model.where(:lat => (south..north), :lng => (east..west))
```

I don't want all the fields, just a few. How would I limit the results to only include columns I choose?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
results = Model.where(:lat => (south..north), :lng => (east..west)).select([:lat, :long, :id])
```

You'll also probably want to include the `:id` in that select if you want your results to behave like reasonable `ActiveRecord` objects.

Edit: Select takes a single arg, can be an array.

Comment: Thanks. One correction to your code above is what unixcharles said in his answer: argument for select needs to be an array of the fields or sql string.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use select

Model.where(...).select(...)

select accept array or raw sql string.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if you want to reuse the data subset filter for readonly models, you can create a 'view' at the database level. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html